# Unable to start Ensime debugger in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ensime

I am using `Emacs 24.5.1` `scala 2.11.5` with ensime. Ensime server runs fine with all error suggestion and other IDE feature etc. But when I start debugging code with  `M-x ensime-db-attach` it prompt with me `Hostname` and `Port`. Which port is it asking for? I want to debug my code locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing `sbt -jvm-debug 5005` from scala home directory resolved the problem. Also in Emacs `M-x ensime-db-attach` when prompted let `Hostname` be localhost and `Port` be 5005.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have used

```
sbt ensimeConfig
```

And in Emacs, you've started the Ensime server. What you need to do, is start an sbt session. And in the sbt console, you invoke

```
ensimeRunDebug fibonacci.Solution
```

(If you have a package fibonacci and a class called Solution.) This hangs on the console.

You then need to go to your Emacs buffer for your source code with the ENSIME menu and put a breakpoint in. You'll get a message that the message is being queued.

Then attach to the debugger - if you use the ENSIME menu, use the Debugger sub-menu and Attach. You'll need to give the hostname and port. Usually, localhost and port 5005.

This should send the breakpoint and run the program. You'll then be debugging.

Comment: After you've issued ensimeRunDebug, the OS should have a new Java process listening on the debug port 5005.

If, when you attach, the sbt prompt closes, you should get an error message saying that it couldn't find your class.

Comment: I should say that the debugger isn't very good. I'd like an Immediate buffer.